# missing jaxb.properties file

Tags: java, jaxb

I got this exception:
Package "com.google.code.linkedinapi.schema" is missing jaxb.properties file.

How  can i do this:
https://code.google.com/p/linkedin-j/source/browse/trunk/linkedin-j/core/src/main/java/com/google/code/linkedinapi/schema/jaxb.properties?spec=svn409&r=409

I want to do it:
javax.xml.bind.context.factory=com.google.code.linkedinapi.schema.impl.JAXBContextFactory

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A `jaxb.properties` file should go under `resources`:

```
src/main/resources/com/google/code/linkedinapui/schema
```

And not under `java`:

```
src/main/java/com/google/code/linkedinapui/schema
```

Comment: I solved this problem by using 1.0.429.jar if you use 1.0.416 it's missing the jaxb plugin.
Jar:(https://code.google.com/p/linkedin-j/downloads/detail?name=linkedin-j-1.0.429-binary.zip&can=2&q=)
And DO NOT USE Maven!!!!!